# Creating database in MYSQL throws this mistakes

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, structure

```
set foreign_key_checks=0

CREATE TABLE product(
id INT(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(100),
category_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id) on update cascade on delete cascade);

CREATE TABLE customer(
id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50),
email varchar(100),
password varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE purchase(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_account_id INT(10),
product id INT(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_account_id) REFERENCES customer(id));


CREATE TABLE category(
id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
kategorija VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id));


CREATE TABLE purchase_item(
purchase_id INT(10),
product_id INT(10),
number_of_items INT(10),
total_price DECIMAL,
FOREIGN KEY (puchase_id) REFERENCES purchase(id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id));
```

**First Mistake**:
[image]

**Second Mistake**:
[image]

Comment: Hello guys. Can someone tell what im doing wrong. many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main errors are due to following lines:

**Error 1**:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0
```

Above line missed statement termination symbol semi-colon ( `;` ).

**Error 2**:

```
product id INT(10),
```

Above line is missing *underscore* between words `product` and `id`.
It should be `product_id`.

Make above changes and your sql script should be working.

Answer (score 0):

well your syntax is nearly correct. In every Creation of an Table you use:

```
column_name INT(number), ...
```

This is correct for the `varchar` datatype but not for the `INT`.
For the `INT` you have to use the **square brackets too [ ]**. So the line i mentioned would become:

```
column_name INT[(10)], ...
```

If you look in the [syntax documentation of the CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) you will find it in the section "data_type".

I hope I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Main errors are due to following lines:

Error 1:

set foreign_key_checks=0
Above line missed statement termination symbol semi-colon ( ; ).

Error 2:

product id INT(10),
Above line is missing underscore between words product and id.
It should be product_id.

Make above changes and your sql script should be working.

Thankyou guys for help!This was correct answer.